# Problem connecting Google Data Studio to MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Server V8.0.28 (Community version) running on Ubuntu 20.04 in a VPS on the internet. I am attempting to use the Google Data Studio MySQL connector (not the Google Cloud one) to connect to the MySQL server, but have not succeeded.

I have a firewall configured to manage inbound traffic and have added the long-ish list of Google servers (listed on the GDS website) to allow access to MySQL - I have confirmed that the firewall is not the issue by also enabling firewall logging which shows relevant traffic being passed through the firewall.

I am able to remotely access the MySQL server from elsewhere successfully.

The GDS failure message is completely unhelpful with no explanation of the cause, simply stating it failed. The hex code generated as part of that message changes every time I test, so I have assumed it is not a status code as such, but an incidence code.

I cut and pasted the username and password details into the GDS configuration forms to ensure no typos there.

I did attempt to enable MySQL debug logging but I wasn't able to successfully start the server with debug enabled. The standard MySQL server log (as placed in /var/log/mysql) reveals one entry when I first try to connect stating there is no reverse DNS lookup for the GDS server attempting the connection (also confirming that the firewall is not the issue) - this message only appears once per server instance, so second and subsequent tests from GDS don't prompt another log entry, not until I restart the MySQL daemon - I assume mysqld is caching connection attempts and feels it doesn't need to log every look up issue, just the first. I feel this is entirely peripheral to the GDS connection problem, but to confirm I put an temporary entry in /etc/hosts - this solved the reverse look up log issue, but not the overall GDS connection one.

Google and others do claim the connection works with v8, although I have come across posts (since Google's announcement of v8 support) stating that others have experienced the same symptom I'm experiencing (admittedly potentially from different causes).

I'd appreciate any suggestions where to go next with this.

UPDATE - 2022-02-16 ----------
As a complex experiment, I did the following

- installed Docker on the same server with MySQL 8
- downloaded and installed a Docker image with MySQL 5.7.37
- exposed the docker image of MySQL 5.7.37 on a different port to the host MySQL 8
- set up the same user and password on 5.7.37
- attempted to create a new GDS data source to the 5.7.37 instance
- it worked first time

UPDATE 2022-02-16 13:08 GMT/UTC - I thought I might as well complete the "loop"

- I reconfigure the Docker container to give MySQL5.7 access to the MySQL8 host instance
- I created new schema + table in the 5.7 instance with the table using the FEDERATED engine to link to an example table in MySQL8.
- I can access the MySQL8 table from GDS (via the MySQL5.7 federated table connection), but goodness knows how inefficient this is of memory, disk and CPU......

UPDATE 2022-02-18 12:11 GMT/UTC --------- Testing if the user authentication mechanism was the source of the GDS connection problem

- set up a second user on the MySQL 8 system
- set the MySQL authentication from "standard" to "caching_sha2_password"
- attempted to connect directly from GDS to my MySQL 8 instance - same failure mode.

So the authentication type is not the problem. Running out of ideas and time to resolve this - hoping that Google does a better job with the GDS MySQL Connector in future.